# How to have one PHP script launch another and capture its output?

Tags: php, redirect, input

This is a little tricky so bear with me:

- I have a PHP script `a.php` that is launched from the command line and data is provided to it via `STDIN`
- I have another PHP script `b.php`
- I want to have `a.php` launch `b.php` *and capture its output*.
- Also, `a.php` has to forward the `STDIN` to `b.php`

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just capturing the stdout of another program (php or not), you can use backticks:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php.
For example:

```
$boutput = `php b.php`;
```

To capture stdin, do this:

```
$ainput = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

Finally, to pipe the contents of a string to an external program, use [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open), as suggested by jeremy's answer.
Specifically, here's what your a.php should contain:

```
$ainput = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
$descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array("pipe", "r"),
        1 => array("pipe", "w"),
        2 => array("pipe", "w")
);
$process = proc_open('php b.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
fwrite($pipes[0], $ainput);
fclose($pipes[0]);
echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]); # echo output of "b.php < stdin-from-a.php"
fclose($pipes[1]);
proc_close($process);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow `B.php` to accept commands via `STDIN` when calling from `A.php`? Would it not be better to just include from that point, and wrap the output around an `ob_start` and `ob_get_flush` command?

Comment: Uh... I can't pass `'php b.php'` to `fopen`.

Comment: Sorry, my first attempt was buggy.  I tested what's there now and it seems to work.

Comment: It works on Windows.... but now it doesn't work on my linux server. Your answer was the most helpful though. +1

Comment: OH NO! `proc_open` is disabled on my server... oh dear... now what?

Answer (score 1):

[`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc_open) should give you the level of control you need to do this.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll give it a shot.